# How to make :hover appearance remain after click/focus in search bar

Tags: javascript, html, css, focus, onfocus

I've got a search bar made of three `div`-containers (magnifying glass icon, input box, arrow icon) within a bigger `div`. Currently I can hover over the search bar to give it a `box-shadow` but I want the `box-shadow` to remain when I click in the text box. Is this possible using just HTML/CSS or do I need to use JavaScript? I've tried using `:focus` but it doesn't seem to work.

```css
.searchbarcontainer {
    width: 482px;
    height: 44px;
    border: 1px solid #dfe1e5;
    border-radius: 2px;
}

.searchbarcontainer:hover, .searchbarcontainer:focus {
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 5px #d9d9d9;
}
```

```html
<div class="searchbarcontainer">    
    <div class="searchbar">
        <div class="magnifier">
            <img class="mag" src="images/magnifier.svg">
        </div>
        <input class="search" type="text">
        <div class="arrow">
            <img class="arw" src="images/arrow.svg">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `.searchbarcontainer:focus` is worked after click.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All you need to do is add attribute `tabindex` (if you need to focus when click on any place on that div) and use `:focus-within`:

```css
.searchbarcontainer {
    width: 482px;
    height: 44px;
    border: 1px solid #dfe1e5;
    border-radius: 2px;
}

.searchbarcontainer:hover {
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 5px #d9d9d9;
}

.searchbarcontainer:focus-within {
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 5px #d9d9d9;
    outline: none;
}
```

```html
<!-- tabindex is not needed if you want to add shadow only when input is focused -->
<div class="searchbarcontainer" tabindex="1">    
    <div class="searchbar">
        <div class="magnifier">
            <img class="mag" src="images/magnifier.svg">
        </div>
        <input class="search" type="text">
        <div class="arrow">
            <img class="arw" src="images/arrow.svg">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Be aware, there is no IE or Edge support for [`:focus-within`](https://caniuse.com/#search=focus-within)

Comment: Amazing! Thanks.